# Bound Datagridview Multiple Column Sort with Lookup ComboBox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, multiple-columns

I am implementing a multi-column sort on a datagridview bound to a datatable. The datagridview uses a combobox for one of the columns where the display member is a string from another table  and the Value member is an integer which provides the foreign key. In a separate datagridview, I can sort easily using a RowComparer via ICompare and the FormattedValue property. However, the main datagridview is bound and won't let me use that interface. Therefore, I am trying to sort the underlying data something like below using a sort string as follows, but that can sort the lookup field, not the ID field. Any ideas?

On the form:

```
private void customSortToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         string sortString = "SectionID ASC, Shift DESC"; //I want the name not ID

         if (sortString != "")
           {
              DataView view = localDataSet.myBaseTable.DefaultView;
              view.Sort = sortString;
              tableBindingSource.DataSource = view;
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps LINQ will give you better access here

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<decimal>("ColumnNameA"))
    .OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<decimal>("ColumnNameB"));
```

I hope this helps.